# Performing a function when button is clicked inside a table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a button inside my tableview cell. How can I convert the following lines of code so that I will be performing the same functions when the button (instead of the row) is clicked? Thanks in advance.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath:    NSIndexPath){

    // Get Cell Label
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! PostCell

    if currentCell.updateBtn.hidden == false {
        valuetoPass = currentCell.favorTitle.text
        valuetoPass_desc = currentCell.descriptionText.text
        postKey = currentCell.post.postKey
        performSegueWithIdentifier("seguetoVC", sender: self)
    }

    if currentCell.bidBtn.hidden == false {
          bidInt = currentCell.post.bids
          postKey = currentCell.post.postKey
          passUsername = currentCell.post.username
          performSegueWithIdentifier("seguetoBidVC", sender: self)
    }

}
```

Comment: can u put code of cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Answer (score 1):

```
    Proper way is, create cell class and add action to cell class from xib. if button pressed then cell class method will be called and it will call delegate method that will be implemented by controller. e.g


protocol TableViewCellDelegate: NSObject {
        func TableViewCell(cell: UITableViewCell, ButtonPressed sender: AnyObject)
    }
    class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
        weak var delegate: CommentTableViewCellDelegate
    }
    IBACtion func sender() {
        self.delegate.TableViewCell(self, ButtonPressed: sender)
    }

    In Controller, implement delegate of cell

    func TableViewCell(cell: UITableViewCell, editButtonPressed sender: AnyObject) {
        var indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableViewComments(forCell: cell)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `@selector` for cell button and assign row value as tag for each row. And when you tap on any cell button you can called method which you added in `@selector` and by button tag, you can get index for that cell.

For Example: In cell for row function:

```
    [cell.btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
cell.btn.tag = indexPth.row;
```

And Function:

```
-(void) btnClick:(UIButton *) btn {
    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:btn.row inSection:0];

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use block for doing this. While creating the cell set the block in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Then call this block whenever the button is tapped in button's IBAction method.

Answer (score 0):

Use Closures for taping events in cells it's soo easy than delegates.

[tutorial](https://www.weheartswift.com/closures/)